# SQL: using a trigger to automatically update the count of an attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a table called BOOKING (keeps tracking of bookings for a hotel) and one of the fields is called booking_status (default value is 'N' (booking incomplete) and value is updated to 'C' when the booking is complete, ie: when the guest leaves the hotel).

I have another table called GUEST (keeps track of all the guests who have ever booked at a hotel) and one of the fields is called guest_booking_count (keeps a count of the total number of complete bookings an individual guest has had).

I want to create a trigger such that when booking_status is updated to 'C' in the booking table, guest_booking_count in the guest is updated by 1.

I have this so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bookingcount_update
AFTER UPDATE OF booking_status ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.booking_status = 'C')
BEGIN
    UPDATE guest
    SET guest_booking_count = guest_booking_count + 1;
END;
```

I am getting a compiler error for this piece of code. I think it may have something to do with the way I am setting the new count.

Could somebody please point out what the error is?

Cheers!

Comment: please add the compiler error output

Comment: BTW you are updating an entire table as there's no `WHERE` in `UPDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one mistake in the code:

- You need to use `WHERE` clause while updating `guest` table with `:new` as cursor name

So your code should look like following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bookingcount_update
AFTER UPDATE OF booking_status ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.booking_status = 'C')
BEGIN
    UPDATE guest
    SET guest_booking_count = guest_booking_count + 1
    WHERE ID=:new.ID; -- add this
END;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bookingcount_update
AFTER UPDATE ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.booking_status != 'C' THEN 
    RETURN;
END IF;

  UPDATE guest
     SET guest_booking_count = guest_booking_count + 1
     WHERE ID=:new.ID;
END;
```

Comment: Perhaps you might add an explanation for the OP and future readers.